# find out who ate with dirty hand in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Create Table #LogEntry
(
    Time nvarchar(30),
    Name nvarchar(30),
    Activity nvarchar(30)
)
go
Select * from #LogEntry

Insert into #LogEntry values('3:28','Sumo','Login'),
                            ('3:31','Sumo','Bathroom'),
                            ('3:33','Sumo','WashHand'),
                            ('3:35','Sumo','Eat'),
                            ('3:32','Rinku','Login'),
                            ('3:34','Rinku','eat'),
                            ('3:35','Rinku','washroom'),
                            ('3:36','Rinku','WashHand')
```

Need help: From the above table I need someone who **doesn't eat** immediately after the washing hand.  Keeping notice that there is time logged with respect to each persons.

I've tried with this below one but its not the exactly what I need

```
Select *, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by name order by name,[time]) Rcnt from #LogEntry
```

```
Time    Name    Activity    Rcnt
3:32    Rinku   Login       1
3:34    Rinku   eat         2
3:35    Rinku   washroom    3
3:36    Rinku   WashHand    4
3:28    Sumo    Login       1
3:31    Sumo    Bathroom    2
3:33    Sumo    WashHand    3
3:35    Sumo    Eat         4
```

Comment: `Time nvarchar(30)` this is a design flaw. There is a `time` data type for a reason. Times aren't strings, and certainly aren't UTF-16 strings.

Comment: As soon as your sample data spans more than one hour of **one assumed day** you will understand the problems of your schema choices.

Comment: Note how your title and description are contradictory. Title says "who ate with dirty hands" while description says "who doesn't eat"

Comment: When the hour has two digits the fun will start: `'10:00'` < `'2:00'` alphabetically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From the above table I need someone who doesn't eat immediately after the washing hand.

Use `lag()`:

```
select le.*
from (select le.*,
             lag(activity) over (partition by name order by time) as prev_activity
      from #logentry le
     ) le
where activity = 'Eat' and prev_activity <> 'Washhand';
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0171a91719bf92e1a1736ada07d7d94c) is a db<>fiddle.

Note:  You should not be storing date/time values as a string.  That is a very bad habit.  SQL Server has a plethora of data types to provide native support for this type of data.